# Why src=".../firebase-app.js" doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

According to Firebase, I should use `src=".../firebase-app.js"` but it doesn't work. So I used `".../firebase.js"` and It worked.

Why?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Log in</title>
    </head>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    <body></body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <h1 id="h1">Log in Page</h1>
    <form id="loginform">
        Username : <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
        Password : <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
    </form>
    <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the exact error when you use firebase-app.js ?

Comment: Both URLs work when you paste them in a new tab, also please mention where exactly Firebase indicated what you should use as `src`. On a side note, the structure of HTML needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase core features are provided by the below link:(required)

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

Whereas firebase.js provides entire SDK:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Please refer document Document provide on official website [firebase - documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)